# Running multiple executables with a single command in CMake and collecting the resulting output in a .txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple toy project with the following structure:

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/TestProject$ tree .
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── first.cpp
└── second.cpp

0 directories, 3 files
```

```
//CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(TestProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(FirstProgram first.cpp)
add_executable(SecondProgram first.cpp)
```

```
//first.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World from the first program" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
//second.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World From the Second Program" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

}
```

What I want to know is

1. How can I gather the executable targets `FirstProgram` and `SecondProgram` together so I can easily run them? I know it would be pretty trivial to setup another target and then set these two as dependencies, but this would only build the dependency targets, rather than actually run them
2. How can I capture the output of these programs and write them to a file? For instance, I'd like to have a file called `first_program_output.txt` that contains the text `Hello, World From the First Program`.

At the moment I'm doing this procedure manually, i.e. running each executable and copying the output. But it'd be great to automate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I gather the executable targets FirstProgram and SecondProgram together so I can easily run them?

```
add_custom_target(run_them_together_easily
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:FirstProgram>
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:SecondProgram>
)
```

> How can I capture the output of these programs and write them to a file?

A "proper way" way would be to add another `cmake` script that does that:

```
 # capture_command_output_to_file.cmake
 # Arguments: COMMAND and OUTPUTFILE
 execute_process(
     COMMAND ${COMMAND}
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE result
 )
 file(WRITE ${OUTPUTFILE} ${result})
 # TODO: Fail if execute_process fails, for example
```

And then call that script with arguments from your cmake:

```
 add_custom_target(capture_output_of_FirstProgram_and_save_it
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
         -D COMMAND=$<TARGET_FILE:FirstProgram> 
         -D OUTPUTFILE=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/first_program_output.txt 
         -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/capture_command_output_to_file.cmake
 )
```

But if you know you will work with shell-ish generator you can just use shell redirection (which will be not portable).

---

Personally I use a main Makefile that is used only as a alias/shortcut targets to easy build&test&deploy&whatever the project and I keep multiple cmake configuration there, all targets in Makefile are phony and the real execution just travels inside cmake binary dir. I use make only because of automatic autocompletion in shell of target names. But I do that because I am working solely in linux environments.

---

> For the first part of this answer, would it be possible to add the commands from a list of targets

```
set(list_of_targets FirstProgram SecondProgram)
# you could wrap this in some macro
# create arguments to be passed to add_custom_target
set(add_custom_target_args)
foreach(i IN LISTS list_of_targets)
     list(APPEND add_custom_target_args COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${i}>)
endforeach()
# then call it
add_custom_target(run_them_together_easily
     ${add_custom_target_args}
)
```

Comment: For the first part of this answer, would it be possible to add the commands from a list of targets, instead of having to type out `COMMAND target1; COMMAND target2; etc.`?

Comment: `from a list of targets` ? How is that list stored? You can do some `foreach`

Comment: At the moment its a `cmake `variable: `set(EXAMPLE_EXECUTABLES_TARGETS "FirstProgram" "SecondProgram")`. The problem is that if you do a `foreach` on `add_custom_target` you actually make many targets, defeating to object of `run_them_together_easily`

Comment: Edited answer. So in a `foreach` create arguments that will be passed to a single `add_custom_target`.